# A riddle by C.S

Tags: riddle

> My scent is fragrant, but danger to some
>   The more I cry, the hotter I become
>   Used oft only when the flow is severed
>   Rarely used after it was bettered

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> Candle?

**My scent is fragrant, but danger to some**

> Some candles are aromatic, some are infused with insecticide

**The more I cry, the hotter I become**

> A candle starts to drip when the wax becomes hot.

**Used oft only when the flow is severed**

> I. e. when there is a blackout.

**Rarely used after it was bettered**

> After light bulb was invented.

Comment: Good job and very quickly as well